# Does neopentyl halide undergo SN1?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

[image: 1-bromo-2,2-dimethylpropane]

Carbocation formed from neopentyl halide is primary in nature. So it is not stable. Although it undergoes rearrangement reaction to form tertiary one, now it can undergo SN1 easily. So if we say it undergoes directly in SN1 will it be okay?

Comment: Neopentyl halides are very poor electrophiles

Comment: @Waylander - if you can provide examples and references, your comment could be turned into a good answer.

Comment: Doesn't the neopentyl carbocation get formed in an E1 reaction?

Answer (score 5):

Neopentyl halides are not good electrophiles in the way that other primary alkyl halides are, primarily due to steric effects but also because of rearrangents and eliminations.

This paper [1](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/nikkashi1972/1995/12/1995_12_1028/_article/-char/en) notes in its abstract that "As a rule, the SN2 reactions of neopentyl bromide and tosylate with sodium alkoxides are extremely retarded by steric hindrance, and the yields of alkyl neopentyl ethers are poor because of side reactions such as neopentyl rearrangement, elimination, and decomposition." This is supportive of the view that an SN1/E1 process may be occurring.

This paper [2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01504a063) confirms rearrangements occur.

I don't think this leads to us being able to say neopentyl bromide undergoes SN1 reactions directly or easily. It is unreactive to nucleophiles; when it does react it does so through mulitple pathways leading to low yields.

Comment: Hello, I had some confusion regarding your last paragraph in the answer. First you state that the view of SN1 is supportive due to rearrangements and then you state that it's not a sole argument to decide whether SN1 proceeds . So according to you, we should always doubt that 3° carbocations can proceed with SN1?

Comment: The main point is that neopentyl halide , even after re-arrangements or whatever be the experimental conditions maybe, always proceeds with a very very slow rate ; about which the answers don't talk about. Atleast explain that what are the multiple pathways are you talking about and how do they affect.

Comment: @Shiva  The multiple pathways are mentioned as " neopentyl rearrangement, elimination, and decomposition". The rearrangements can occur by methyl shift as described in the second reference, other pathways might include dimerisation and cyclopropane formation.

Comment: So why don't the rearrangement makes the rate faster?

Comment: They do not affect the rate - only the outcome. Everything happens slowly with the neopentyl series. Formation of a primary cation is slow because it is unfavourable. You get mostly unchanged starting material out of these reactions.

Comment: Thanks very much, now I understand. What I conclude finally is that formation of the very first carbocation is a very slow process due to it's unstability. Finally due to rearrangements and other processes you mentioned ( of which I don't know much as I am not a chemist) , this time is extended further and though the product will be formed , but very slowly.